# Check if one number is equal to another

Tags: java, android, count

I've got an xp counter in my app which counts things like button clicks and other things. When the xp reaches a certain number the level increases. I've written it like this at the moment:

```
private void Levels(){
ref.child(userID).child("XP").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Integer current_xp = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (current_xp== 50) {
               
                Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
                level_counter.Counter();

            }
            if (current_xp==100){
                Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
                level_counter.Counter();
            }
            if (current_xp==150){
                Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
                level_counter.Counter();
            }
        }
```

How can I rewrite this so I only have to write the level count method once? so that it levels up every 50 points.

Comment: if(current_xp % 50 == 0)

Comment: Unrelated: method names go camelCase() and should contain a verb in java. so `Counter()` is really a bad method name.

Comment: thanks Dominik thats works great. and ive also learnt somthing new. cheers :)

Comment: *its easy to understand* it could be even easier, that's why almost everybody uses the same style. Making your code readable should be top priority, especially when having other people read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change level at every 50 points you can do it like below:

```
if (current_xp % 50 == 0) {
   int level = current_xp / 50;
}
```

Comment: This code will increase the level just in the case you have exactly n*50 xp, so if you have 51 you will still be level 0 until you reach 100 xp exactly.

Comment: Nope. In java int division 51 / 50 returns 1, 52 / 50 also returns 1 until to 100. 100(or 100..149) returns 2.

Comment: Yep, but you wont enter the conditional because `51 % 50 = 1` so the level wont be recalculated

Comment: Have you noticed that in the original code, level(int) increases at every 50 points? `if (current_xp== 50) {

                Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
                level_counter.Counter();

            }
            if (current_xp==100){
                Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
                level_counter.Counter();
            }
            if (current_xp==150){
                Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
                level_counter.Counter();
            }`

Comment: And also in the question, the author says that **when the xp = a certain number the level increases**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use modulus operator and rewrite the if-else blocks in below mentioned way.

```
if (current_xp % 50 == 0) {
    Level_Counter level_counter = new Level_Counter(userID);
    level_counter.Counter();
}
```